# Search and Sum based on selection

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I tried Sum, CountIf, Dsum, SumProduct

I have a Userform with a ComboBox "History_Select_Debtor". The RowSource for the ComboBox is "Debtor_list_Debtors" - A Dynamic Named Range on WorkSheet "DebtorList". It consists of Customer Names from A2:A24 but will grow eventually.

The UserForm also Has a Textbox for Total Items Purchased Named "txtPurchased".

With each Transaction a Record is saved on Worksheet "InvoiceList" which consists of 7 Columns.

Each of these Columns have Dynamic Named Ranges

```
A = "Debtor" (Invoice_list_Debtor)
B = "Item" (Invoice_list_Item)
C = "Price" (Invoice_list_Price)
D = "Date" (Invoice_list_Date)
E = "Time" (Invoice_list_Time)
F = "Balance" (Invoice_list_Balance)
G = "Payed" (InvoiceList_Payed)
```

The Record Saved in the Item Column is Text;

"Payed Balance","Added Balance","Quarter Item","Half Item","1 Item" - "10 Items"

I need to, "Based on the combo selection (History_Select_Debtor)", Reference that Particilar Debtor with "InvoiceList", sum up the total Number of Purchases and display that Value in "txtPurchased".

I need a specific Value to be assigned to each Item e.g. "Quarter Item" = 0.25 or "5 Item = 5".

If as an example "Adrian" has 7 Transactions recorded on InvoiceList

```
Added Balance
Quarter Item
Half Item
Quarter Item
10 Items
4 Items
Payed Balance
```

The Value to be displayed in "txtPurchased" would be "15".

I've a Macro that sums up the total Purchases;

It sums up the Total Row rather than just whichever Debtor is Selected in "History_Select_Debtor"

```
'-------Total Transactions----------------------------------------------------------------------
Set ws = Worksheets("DebtorList")
    With Me
    'Starting point of lookup data
    Rw = .History_Select_Debtor.ListIndex + 2
    History_Select_Debtor.List = Range("Debtor_list_Debtors").Value
txtTransactions.Value = Application.CountIf(Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), History_Select_Debtor)
End With
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another Macro I've made which also won't work;

```
=SUM(IF(Invoice_list_Item="Quarter Item",0.25,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="Half Item",0.5,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="1 Item",1,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="2 Items",2,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="3 Items",3,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="4 Items",4,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="5 Items",5,0)+IF(Invoice_list_Item="10 Items",10,0))
```

The Issue with this one is that given I use the Invoice_list_Debtor as the RowSource for my ComboBox I end up with over 170 duplicate Names.

Here is the Source Code to the Page I need to code to work on;

```
Public ListTable As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    History_Select_Debtor.List = Range("Debtor_list_Debtors").Value
    History_Select_Debtor = ""

Label6.Visible = False
Label7.Visible = False
Label8.Visible = False
Label9.Visible = False
Label10.Visible = False
Label11.Visible = False
Label12.Visible = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("InvoiceList")
ListTable = ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Me.ListBox1.List = Range("A2:G" & ListTable).Value
Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;80;70;100;80;80;80"

'-----------Listview--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Dim ws As Worksheet
    'Dim lngRow As Long
    'Dim lvwItem As ListItem
    'Dim lngEndCol As Long
    'Dim lngCol As Long
    'Dim lngEndRow As Long
    'Dim lngItemIndex As Long
    'Dim blnHeaders() As Boolean
    'Dim Rw As Long

    'Set ws = Worksheets("InvoiceList")
    'lngEndCol = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    'lngEndRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    'ListView1.Gridlines = True
    'lngRow = 1
    'With ListView1

        '.View = lvwReport
        'For lngCol = 1 To lngEndCol
            '.ColumnHeaders.Add , , ws.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text, ws.Columns(lngCol).ColumnWidth + 59.6
        '.BackColor = vbBlack
        'Next
        'For lngRow = 2 To lngEndRow
            'lngCol = 1
            'lngItemIndex = 0
            'Set lvwItem = .ListItems.Add(, , (ws.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text))
            'For lngCol = 2 To lngEndCol
                'lngItemIndex = lngItemIndex + 1
                'lvwItem.SubItems(lngItemIndex) = Format(ws.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Text, ws.Cells(lngRow, lngCol).NumberFormat) 'Adds Value from Current Row and Column 1
            'Next
        'Next

            '.TextBackground = lvwTransparent

    'End With
'-----------Listview--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-----------ChartSpace---------------------------------------------------
   Dim ChtSpc As OWC11.ChartSpace
   Dim cht As OWC11.ChChart
   Dim Sps As OWC11.Spreadsheet
   Dim owcChart As OWC11.ChartSpace
   Dim Balance As String

   Balance = Range("B1").Value
   Set owcChart = Me.ChartSpace1
   Set ChtSpc = Me.ChartSpace1
   Set Sps = Me.Spreadsheet1
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DebtorList")   ' change to you worksheet name

   Sps.Range("A1:B100") = ws.Range("A1:B100").Value   ' Set worksheet range to sheet control range

   Set ChtSpc.DataSource = Sps   ' set sheet control as chart control source

   Set cht = ChtSpc.Charts.Add  ' Add blank chart

   With cht ' Set data for chart
    .SetData chDimCategories, 0, "A2:A25"    ' change to your category range
    .SeriesCollection(0).SetData chDimValues, 0, "B2:B25" ' change to your series 1 range
    '.PlotArea.FlipHorizontal
    '.PlotArea.FlipVertical
    '.PlotArea.RotateClockwise
    '.SeriesCollection.Add
    '.SeriesCollection(1).SetData chDimValues, 0, "A1:A24" ' change to your series 2 range

    'By changing the layout we can control how the charts are presented
    'inside the Chart space.

   .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
   .Border.Color = vbWhite
   .Border.Weight = Thick

   '.Type = chChartTypeColumn3D
   '.Type = chChartTypeAreaStacked

End With

Me.Spreadsheet1.Visible = False     ' hide the sheet control

'Set up the charts and manipulate some of their properties.

With owcChart.Charts(0)

    'The data reference must be of the datatype string.
    'The last parameter specify if each row represent a serie or not.

    '.HasTitle = True

    With .PlotArea
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        '.Border.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        '.Border.DashStyle = chLineSolid
        '.Border.Weight = Thick
    End With

    'With .Title
        '.Caption = Balance
        '.Font.Name = "Verdana"
        '.Font.Size = 10
        '.Font.Bold = True
        '.Font.Color = RGB(50, 205, 50)
    'End With

    With .Axes(0).Font
        .Name = "Verdana"
        .Size = 8
        '.Bold = True
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

    With .Axes(1).Font
        .Name = "Verdana"
        .Size = 8
        '.Bold = True
        .Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

    'With .Axes(0).MinorGridlines
        '.Line.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With

    'With .Axes(0).MajorGridlines
        '.Line.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With

    'With .Axes(1).MinorGridlines
        '.Line.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With

    'With .Axes(1).MajorGridlines
            '.Line.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    'End With

    With .SeriesCollection(0)
        '.Border.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
        .Caption = Balance
        .Line.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

    'With .SeriesCollection(1)
        '.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        '.Caption = Balance
    'End With

    '.HasLegend = True

    'With .Legend
        '.Position = chLegendPositionBottom
        '.Border.Color = vbWhite
        '.LegendEntries(2).Visible = False
    'End With

End With
'------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub


Private Sub cmdClose_History_Click()

  Unload Me
  frmMenu.Show

End Sub

Private Sub History_Select_Debtor_Change()

'--------Total Purchased-----------------------------------------------
    'Worksheets("InvoiceList").Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Me.History_Select_Debtor
    'Me.txtPurchased = Worksheets("Summary").[C2] 'the cell containing the SUBTOTAL
'-------------------------------------------------------

Label6.Visible = True
Label7.Visible = True
Label8.Visible = True
Label9.Visible = True
Label10.Visible = True
Label11.Visible = True
Label12.Visible = True

FilterList 0, Me.History_Select_Debtor.Text

Me.cmdClose_History.SetFocus

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rw As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("DebtorList")

    'Get row based on ComboBox ListIndex
    With Me
    'Starting point of lookup data
    Rw = .History_Select_Debtor.ListIndex + 2
    'Data to be displayed based on selection
    txtBalance.Value = FormatCurrency(Expression:=ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value, _
    NumDigitsAfterDecimal:=2)

End With
'-------Total Transactions----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set ws = Worksheets("DebtorList")
    With Me
    'Starting point of lookup data
    Rw = .History_Select_Debtor.ListIndex + 2
    History_Select_Debtor.List = Range("Debtor_list_Debtors").Value
txtTransactions.Value = Application.CountIf(Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), History_Select_Debtor)
End With
'-------Total Payed------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
txtPayed.Value = FormatCurrency(Expression:=Application.SumIf(Range("Invoice_list_Debtor"), _
History_Select_Debtor.Value, Range("Invoice_list_Price")), _
    NumDigitsAfterDecimal:=2)

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose _
  (Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'   Prevents use of the Close button
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FilterList(iCtrl As Long, sText As String)
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sCrit As String
sCrit = "*" & UCase(sText) & "*"
Set ws = Worksheets("InvoiceList")
With Me.ListBox1

ListTable = ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
.List = ws.Range("A2:G" & ListTable).Value

For iRow = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If Not UCase(.List(iRow, iCtrl)) Like sCrit Then
.RemoveItem iRow
End If
Next iRow

        'Determine number of columns
        .ColumnCount = 7
        'Set column widths
        .ColumnWidths = "50;80;70;100;80;80;80"
        'Insert the range of data supplied
        For x = 2 To 3 'loop the numeric columns - 3 to 4
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 'loop through the rows of columns 3 to 5
                .List(i, x) = Format(.List(i, x), "$#,##")
            Next i
        Next x
                For x = 5 To 6 'loop the numeric columns - 4 to 5
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 'loop through the rows of columns 3 to 5
                .List(i, x) = Format(.List(i, x), "$#,##")
            Next i
        Next x
                For x = 4 To 4 'loop the numeric columns - 3 to 4
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 'loop through the rows of columns 3 to 5
                .List(i, x) = Format(.List(i, x), "[$-409]h:mm AM/PM;@")
            Next i
        Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one issue here I believe ...

To get the total number of invoiced items for a debtor you can

1. (auto)filter the InvoiceList for your current Debtor
2. display the sum of invoiced items using the `=SUBTOTAL(109,InvoiceSheet!$F:$F)` worksheet function (asuming the invoice sheet is named `[InvoiceSheet]` ;-) )

I would even suggest to have that =SUBTOTAL on a seperate sheet (Sheet2), so it's location is constant. Don't use `ControlSource()` on the text field in the dialog, but set `Locked = True`

You can set up Autofilter on [InvoiceSheet] once and use the Sub

```
Private Sub History_Select_Debtor_Change()
    Worksheets("InvoiceSheet").Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Me.History_Select_Debtor
    Me.txtPurchased = Worksheets("Sheet2").[A1] 'the cell containing the SUBTOTAL
End Sub
```

to fire the filter and get the value of the SUBTOTAL formula back into the dialog.

For the transition of quantities from text to number I would suggest to create an extra sheet [QTYCode] looking like

```
         A        B    ...
  +------------+-----+----
1 |Text        |Value|
2 |Quarter item| 0.25|
3 |Half item   |  0.5|
4 |1 item      |    1|
5 |2 item      |    2|
6 |3 item      |    3|
...
```

where column A (except header row) serves as RowSource() for the QTY selection box, and for each record you create in [InvoiceSheet] you save not only the selected QTYText, but as well an extra column containing a =VLOOKUP() formula that converts text into value (and base your =SUBTOTAL() on that new column - of course)

Hope that helps

Good luck - MikeD

Comment: Thanks a heap mike worked great, I made the ItmCode Table as you suggested and used;

Comment: Sheets("Summary").Range("C2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range("InvoiceList_ItmCode"))

But I'm having a problem with the AutoFilter when I view InvoiceList in my Listview it doesnt show new Records now; In Collumn "I" on InvoiceList I've added the ItmCode Collumn with a code next to each item on the InvoiceList and did this In the Purchase Source

Dim QtyCode As Variant
QtyCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Purchase_Select_Quantity.Value, Range("PriceList_Quantity_Table"), 2, False)

Problem I'm having is when I make a new Purchase now it deletes Rows

Comment: It's like with the AutoFilter set it fails to place new Invoice records in the correct position when I make a purchase, now that I have the ItmCode Collumn and the ItmCode Table is there another method I can use rather than AutoFilter?

Comment: Beautifull, fixed thank you so much for your help Mike, the code I used to fix it;

Me.txtPurchased = Application.SumIf(Range("InvoiceList_Table_ItmCode"), Me.History_Select_Debtor.Value, Range("InvoiceList_ItmCode"))

Comment: make sure that when you define the AutoFilter, you select complete rows (requires that header row is row #1) - inserting new records must be done with AutoFilter set to "Show All Data". I suggest you switch AutoFilter ON to the current argument on the "Change" trigger of your selection box, and set it to "Show All Data" when the form looses focus and before you insert records. Anything more .... just post (European timezone here :-) )